# Entity Framework Model with a max child record property

Tags: entity-framework

I have a couple of simple EF models with a parent child relationship.  The children are essentially audit records.  I am wanting to use the audits to get the min date to determine the "Create Date" of the parent.

The two models directly match the SQL Database as you would expect with the exception of the derived "CreatedDate" field that I was hoping for EF to translate into a simple "Max" subquery.

I am using the EF Repository Pattern with the Unit Of Work pattern and trying to keep things really simple with the SQL Server doing the MAX query.

I have tried using automapper to map in my service layer but this generates an SQL query per parent.

Any ideas?

```
public class Item
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual IEnumerable<Audit> Audits { get; set; }

    //Read only create date and problem property
    [NotMapped]
    public DateTime CreatedDate
    {
        get
        {
            return Audits.Max(a => a.AuditDate);
        }
    }
}

public class Audit
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ItemId { get; set; }
    public DateTime AuditDate { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: What version of EF?

Comment: What do you mean by "EF repository pattern"?

Comment: http://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Queryable-Extensions.html

Answer (score 0):

I could well be wrong but I don't think EF will support this; either you pull in all of the Audit records for an Item
e.g.

```
var item = _context.Items.Include("Audit").FirstOrDefault(i=>i.Id==1)
```

in which case the method will work.

Or, you could create a view mapped to a new entity (or QueryType if you are using EF Core) that contains Id, Name, and CreateDate only.

e.g

```
SELECT Id,Name=CreateDate=Max(CreateDate) from Items group by Id,Name
```

Now since I always use views for this kind of thing I do stand to be corrected on the first point!